# How can I scan more than 1 integer?

Tags: c

I just started learning C language in school, but the teacher insists that I use this when I want the user to add more than 2 integers:

However I feel like this isn't correct because how can the computer know which number is which?

```
int main ( )
{
    int a, b;
    printf( "put two numbers" );
    scanf( "%d", &a, &b );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post code as text, not as image.

Comment: Please don't post links to images of code — include the code in your question.  If you're not sure how, it's easy — copy the code from your editor or wherever and paste it, without any tabs, into the text box.  Then select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it as code.  You've only got 6 lines!

Comment: Oh i see Ill change that now, thank you

Comment: Your compiler should be warning you that this code is wrong. Also your teacher is very wrong

Comment: @UweKeim: But don't then go and make the image visible — make the OP add the text to the question.

Comment: You can either use 2 `%d` units in the format string, or use 2 calls to `scanf()`, one to read `a` and the other to read `b`.  Don't forget to check that `scanf()` succeeded in reading the correct number of values.

Comment: use arrays and loops to add more numbers.

Comment: This is a good time to try and think logically about it... You (should) know that one `"%d"` reads one value, so how would you then read two values?

Comment: You are not writing the correct question. Your teacher did not want you to use `scanf("%d", &a, &b)`. Quite possibly, your teacher wanted you to use `scanf("%d", &x)` in a loop, so that you could get any number of numbers, adding each one to a sum as you go. In other words, the assignment is to learn to use code in a loop to handle a variable number of things at run-time, not to write fixed code that handles only a set number of things. Alternatively, your teacher might have wanted you to use `scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)`, with two `%d` instead of one. It depends on what your class was learning.

Answer (score 1):

to read two numbers :

```
if (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) == 2)
    printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
else
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to read two integers\n");
```

if the number of numbers to read is variable read them one by one in a loop

Answer (score 1):

You need a conversion specifier for each argument:

```
scanf( "%d %d", &a, &b );
```

You should check the result of `scanf` to make sure you successfully read two items:

```
if ( scanf( "%d %d", &a, &b ) == 2 )
{
  // process a and b
}
else
{
  // at least one entry was not an integer, print error message and exit
}
```

If you want to give the user a chance to enter two numbers correctly, use a loop, and clear out any unread input before prompting again:

```
while ( scanf( "%d %d", &a, &b ) != 2 )
{
  // clear out input stream up to the next newline:
  while ( getchar() != '\n' )
    ; // empty loop

  printf( "Error on input, try again: " );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have one format for every variable, but in your Question, one is clearly missing):

```
if ( scanf( "%d %d", &a, &b ) != 2 )
{
    printf( "Error,s canf()\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Another way would be to read the values into an array like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 2

int main ( void )
{
    int arr[SIZE];

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < SIZE ; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Give a number:> " );
        if ( scanf( "%d", &arr[i] ) != 1 )
        {
            printf( "Error,scanf()\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    for ( int j = 0 ; j < SIZE ; j++ )
    {
        printf( "ARR[%d] = %d\n",j, arr[j] );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Give a number:> 4
Give a number:> 2
ARR[0] = 4
ARR[1] = 2
```

Comment: That's just going to store the values read in the array, though, and won't change your a and b variables. So I'm not sure what they're for?

Comment: @Rup There was not my intention to change values of a and b :|

Comment: @Rup `How can I scan more than 1 integer?` That was the Question, isn't it? In OP post there is the problem of missing the format specifier and I did mentioned in my Question. But again the title said: `How can I scan more than 1 integer?` No I need to ask you what is wrong with showing to the OP another way of scanning two integers that made you to Down vote this Answer?

Comment: I updated my Answer according to the Question.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote sorry. Yes, using an array is sensible. I was just checking / clarifying what you expected to happen to a and b, and why you declared them in the first place.

Comment: I've put the array version back because it was interesting, and +1. It's not necessary to initialize the array though because you've overwriting all values in it in the loop. And it's not variable length either really since you're setting the length with a #defined constant.